# The product of two symmetric groups acting on a function

Tags: permutation, group-theory

Considering the rational function
$$
\small 
\begin{align*}
f&(x_1,x_2,x_3;y_1,y_2,y_3)\\
&=\frac{\left(1-\frac{y_1}{x_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_2}{x_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_3}{x_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_1}{x_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_2}{x_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_3}{x_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_1}{x_3}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_2}{x_3}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_3}{x_3}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{x_3}{x_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{x_3}{x_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_3}{y_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{y_3}{y_2}\right)} \\
\end{align*}
$$
in $6$ variables, I would like to compute the sum
$$\sum_{w\in S_3\times S_3}w(f),$$
where the first copy of $S_3$ in $w$ is permuting the indices of the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ while the second copy of $S_3$ is permuting the indices of the variables $y_1,y_2,y_3$.

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_, y1_, y2_, y3_] := ((1 - y1/x1) (1 - y2/x1) (1 - y3/x1) (1 - y1/x2) (1 - y2/x2) (1 - y3/x2) (1 - y1/x3) (1 - y2/x3) (1 - y3/x3))/((1 - x2/x1) (1 - x3/x1) (1 - x3/x2) (1 - y2/y1) (1 - y3/y1) (1 - y3/y2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sum[
 f @@ Join[{x1, x2, x3}[[σ]], {y1, y2, y3}[[τ]]],
 {σ, Permutations[Range[3]]}, 
 {τ, Permutations[Range[3]]}
 ]
```